# How to tell if a page is loaded as a popup or in a separate tab in chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

My Chrome extension has a page that is seen in a popup or as a separate tab. When it seen as a separate tab, I need to show a small button at the corner of the page. But I couldn't find a way to detect when a page is loaded in its own tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [chrome.extension.getViews](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/extension#method-getViews), which returns an array of window objects.

```
var tabs = chrome.extension.getViews({ type: "tab"})
if(tabs[0]) {
  console.log("inside tab")
}
var popups = chrome.extension.getViews({ type: "popup"})
if(popups[0]) {
  console.log("inside popup")
}
```

Or [chrome.tabs.getCurrent](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-getCurrent), which returns a [tab object](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#type-Tab) in the callback.

```
chrome.tabs.getCurrent(function(tab) {
  if(tab) {
    console.log("inside tab")
  } else {
    console.log("inside popup")
  }
})
```

Comment: A more accurate test in the first case would be comparing `window` to the object returned.